# Comparing 2 times and getting the difference in minutes

Tags: python, datetime

i am trying to get the time difference using two times. i am getting 2 epoch timestamps from an api, converting them to a datetime, and then trying to compare them and get the time difference in minutes.

No errors in console.. the minutes just stay at 0.0 when i return it.

```
onlinestatus = (data["session"]["online"])


    if onlinestatus is False:
        theNewLineString = "\n"
        lastLogout_string = "LastLogout: "
        log_in = int(data2["player"]["lastLogin"])
        log_out = int(data2["player"]["lastLogout"])
        log_in_converted = timedate = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d\n%I:%M %p', time.localtime(log_in / 1000))
        log_out_converted = timedate = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d\n%I:%M %p', time.localtime(log_out / 1000))
        diff = datetime.strptime(log_in_converted, '%Y-%m-%d\n%I:%M %p') - datetime.strptime(log_out_converted, '%Y-%m-%d\n%I:%M %p')

        return str("Online: ") + "`" + "False" + "`" + theNewLineString + theNewLineString + lastLogout_string + "`" + log_out_converted + theNewLineString + "`" + "Minutes Since Last Logout: " + "`" + str(diff.seconds/60) + "`"
```

I know everything else works. I am using a discord bot to return everything and here is what it returns:

```
Online: False

LastLogout: 2020-05-16
12:27 PM
Minutes Since Last Logout: 0.0
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is your issue is not do to `=timedate` in  `log_in_converted = timedate =... ` and `log_out_converted = timedate=... `

Comment: @Renaud I removed it and it's still not working, i have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: You are doing `diff =  login - logout`, this should be the opposite.

Comment: @Renaud This makes no difference, `timedate` is never used, and an expression like `a = b = 3` just gives two names, `a` and `b`, to the object `3`, nothing more.

Comment: So check diff.total_seconds() on behalf of diff.seconds()

Comment: It will be negative, as the login and logout are reversed in the difference.

Comment: The logic doesn't make any sense to me: if you want to determine the amount of time since the last logout, why would you compare the time of the last logout *to the time of the last login*? Shouldn't you be comparing the time of the last logout to *the time that it is now*?

Comment: Anyway - when you say that you "know everything else works" - could you show the values that you get? For example, what result do you get for `log_in` and `log_out`, and what result do you get for `diff` without attempting any formatting?

Comment: lastLogin: 1589469394594
lastLogout: 1589469437979

Comment: So, the logout takes place after the login, and login - logout will be negative.

Comment: If you have numeric timestamps in the first place, why all the conversion to datetime and strings? Just take the difference of the numbers and adjust to what ever unit (e.g. minutes) you want. Any code that is not there, can't do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 2 datetime objects:

```
d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
d2 = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Now you can substract one from the other:

```
(d2 - d1)
```

This gives the result:

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3, microseconds=516614)
```

Then you can call the 'seconds' item and convert it to minutes:

```
(d2 - d1).seconds / 60
```

Hope this helps.